# Location permission issue Android 13

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-13

Location permission is directly going to isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied on Android 13. It is not asking permission to user. Even if I grant the permission in settings also, it is going to isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied.

```
 val permissions = ArrayList<String>()
        permissions.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
        Dexter.withActivity(this).withPermissions(permissions)
            .withListener(object : MultiplePermissionsListener {
                override fun onPermissionsChecked(report: MultiplePermissionsReport) {
                    when {
                        report.areAllPermissionsGranted() -> {
                            checkAppUpdate()
                        }
                        report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied -> {
                            startActivity(
                                Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS,
                                    Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        else -> {
                            checkPermission()
                        }
                    }

                }

                override fun onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(
                    permissions: List<PermissionRequest>,
                    token: PermissionToken
                ) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest()
                }
            }).onSameThread().check()
```

Comment: have you declared identical permission in manifest also?

Comment: Yes , I have entered permissions in manifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ask for COARSE location permission.

And only when the user allowed that ask for FINE.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was, another dependency was adding maxSdk version which in turn was denying the permissions without even showing up the dialog. What I would recommend you is to check your android manifest file in the bottom tab look for Merged Manifest and look at your uses permission. If you find any maxSdk use this at end of permission to remove it.
for example I used:
 `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />`

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />`

Answer (score 1):

At first, Dexter is not under active maintenance anymore and I would not recommend to use it when you work on Android 13. The new way is also way more straight forward

Example:

```kotlin
    private val permissionList = arrayOf(
        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
    )

    private val activityResultLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(RequestMultiplePermissions()) { permissions ->
            if (!permissions.values.contains(false)) {
//                contactsProvider.addMockContactList()
                permissionState.value = true
                Log.d(TAG, "activityResultLauncher")
            }
        }
    private fun checkPermissions() {
        val hasPermission = permissionList.all {
            checkSelfPermission(it) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions")
        if (!hasPermission) {
            activityResultLauncher.launch(permissionList)
        } else {
            getContactList()
            permissionState.value = true
        }
    }
```

And second, for getting location information you need two permissions: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`. Since fine location depends on coarse location, it will get instantly revoked everytime.